# openssh-server privilege separation bug strikes again 16.xx Lubuntu

Tags: boot, ssh, lubuntu, startup, upstart

I've been fighting an inconsistent startup problem with the 16.xx releases of Lubuntu and openssh-server. It won't start at boot as it should and manually starting "sudo service ssh start" yields an old and well discussed bug about the privilege separation directory missing /var/run/sshd.

I've had this problem on 5 machines so I know it's not "just that one machine" and it's still dogging me. I've read tons of bug reports and articles many marked solved that yielded no help or even insight. The start up scripts check for the directory and should create it if it's missing but never seem to do it. I can only guess something else is starting it rather than the scripts I'm looking at that just fail if the directory is not there.

I'm ignorant of how Ubuntu is starting anything these days. Between talks of things, hearing about delays of those things and then having them actually implemented I don't know what is going on. Init, Upstart, X, Mir, apt, snapd, (crackle pop) it's become like alphabet soup but you never know what language you will get until you open the can! Rantiness aside I'm just saying my diagnosisFU is weak these days and I'd appreciate some help. I can say the Ubuntu server 16.04 sshd seems solid. This appears to be an Lubuntu specific issue as my one Xubuntu install seems OK as well. Has anyone figured out why this is happening and how to rectify it?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to make it actually start at boot as expected...